# Adding label in py2neo not working

Tags: python, neo4j, py2neo

I am using this code:

```
 n1 = Node("X", name=w1)
 graph.create(n1)
 n1.add_label(u2)
```

But it's simply not adding this label `u2`, even from the Python prompt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According [the docs](http://py2neo.org/2.0/essentials.html#nodes) you should add labels to a node in this way:

```
alice = Node("Person", name="Alice")
alice.labels.add("Employee")
```

In your case, you are using a different method name (add_label) and not passing a string. Try:

```
n1 = Node("X", name="w1")
graph.create(n1)
n1.labels.add("u2")
```

Note the `"u2"` instead of `u2`.

Comment: It doesn't recognize the add function:

Comment: >>> import py2neo
>>> lamb = Node("X", name="lamborghini")
>>> lamb.labels.add("SUPERCAR")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'add'

Comment: @ugp which version of py2neo are you using?

Comment: >>> py2neo
<module 'py2neo' from '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/py2neo/__init__.pyc'>

Comment: The documentation is outdated! https://py2neo.org/v4/data.html#py2neo.data.Node.node.labels.add. Refer https://github.com/technige/py2neo/issues/724 for solution

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to update node with list of labels then you can try:

```
nodeLabelList = ["Person", "Admin"]
node.update_labels(nodeLabelList)
```

This is for py2neo v4.